# ImportError: No module named cvtypes

Tags: python, python-2.7

can someone help me to say that I get this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xpfotografia/Documentos/deteccion4.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cvtypes import cv
ImportError: No module named cvtypes
```

Comment: You mean `ctypes` - http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html?

Answer (score 1):

The docs at http://www.cs.unc.edu/~gb/blog/2007/02/04/python-opencv-wrapper-using-ctypes/ have:

```
from CVtypes import cv
win = 'Show Cam'
cv.NamedWindow(win)
# rest snipped....
```

as an example... so I guess you need to change your import to include a capital **CV** as above

Comment: Yes, but as I do I call that function or library I need.

Comment: @Ivan Sorry - I don't understand you?

Comment: el ejemplo que pusiste es como debe de ir?

Comment: the example you put is as it should be?

Comment: So you're doing `from CVtypes import cv` and it hasn't fixed your problem in `deteccion4.py`?

Comment: @IvanGuerrero Did you want to update your question, with information related to what/any further errors you're getting?

Comment: excuse me mr Jon. I have this problem :
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xpfotografia/Documentos/detec6.py", line 92, in <module>
    faceCascade = cv.Load("haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
TypeError: OpenCV returned NULL   Do you know some thing?

Comment: @IvanGuerrero I have no idea - you'll need to look at the OpenCV documentation and see under what circumstance cv.Load would fail